# Easy way to remap Option key to Up arrow on Mac?

Tags: keyboard, mapping

My up arrow key has failed (MBP mid 2012). Apple tells me I require keyboard replacement at $300. I want to remap the option key to up arrow key as a temporary solution (keys are very close).

I am running Mojave, 10.14.6. I am having difficulty locating exact codes for these keys and code I need to write and installation instructions for Mojave  10.14.6. Any help would be appreciated. I looked into 3rd party keyboard mapping programs, I am leery of these programs for security reasons.

Comment: What security reasons? Keymappers are not keyloggers. Karabiner is open source, so its code is available to check.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did a google search on concerns regarding the product you mention. From what I found, you can rebuild it from sources, however it also ships with several binary files that are required during linking. The sources for these binary files are included, however the compilation for these fail, but this is ignored and the shipped compiled files are used. I actually had the product installed, looks quite fancy, but once I read this I immediately removed it from my system as key mappers are in an ideal position to log keyboard input. Just trying to be careful.